# In java regular expression how to split by dot but excluding if it contains backslash

Tags: java, regex

In java, I am having a string containing dot and I want to split the string by dot but how to exclude if it contains backslash.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 ="test.env.PM1/.0";
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s1.split("[.]")));//[test, env, PM1/, 0]

    }
}
```

output expected:

```
[test, env, PM1/.0]
```

So, how can to exclude splitting if dot followed by a backslash is there.

Comment: try `(?<!/)\\.`

Comment: It is showing invalid escape sequence.    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s1.split("(?<!\/)\\.")));

Comment: @CodeManiac `/` is not special in Java regex. There is no need to escape it (if that was your intention).

Comment: as @Pshemo mentioned it's not special character in Java regex so no need to escape `/`, so you can use `(?<!/)\\.`

Comment: @vikram is `/` always used to escape `.`? OR it is possible that `/` will be end of token `.` after it way represent delimiter? Also are you sure it is ``/`` and not ``\``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a negative look-behind assertion to ensure it does not have a preceding forward slash.

```
String s1 ="test.env.PM1/.0";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s1.split("(?<!/)\\.")));
// [test, env, PM1/.0]
```

[Try it online here](https://ideone.com/FX6bUU)

For more explanation see [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) *(emphasis mine)*

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", **are zero-length assertions** just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors explained earlier in this tutorial. The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called "assertions". **They do not consume characters in the string**, but only assert whether a match is possible or not. Lookaround allows you to create regular expressions that are impossible to create without them, or that would get very longwinded without them.
>   ...  **Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not followed by something else.**